# How to bulk update while overriding "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX" constraint?

Tags: postgresql

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ranking    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name         TEXT  NOT NULL,
    is_deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX exists_const ON my_table ranking WHERE (is_deleted = FALSE);

| ranking |  name  | is_deleted |
|   1     |  A     |   true     |
|   2     |  B     |   true     |
|   1     |  C     |   true     |
|   1     |  D     |   false    |
|   2     |  E     |   false    |
|   3     |  F     |   false    |
```

So when I want to update a new ranking for D, E, F to be

```
UPDATE "my-table" AS t SET "ranking"=v."ranking" FROM 
(VALUES(1, 'F', 'false'),(2, 'D', 'false'), (3, 'E', 'false'))
AS v("ranking","name", 'is_deleted') WHERE v.name = t.name

|   1     |  F     |   false    |
|   2     |  D     |   false    |
|   3     |  E     |   false    |
```

I have `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "exists_const"` ERROR.
Even though the new rows will not have duplicates at all. How can I perform such update?

Comment: You mentioned `v.id = t.id` , but there is no `id` in the table nor in the values. Please correct me if I am missing some thing.

Comment: sorry it suppose to be v.name = t.name. But you get the idea right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by Deferring the check at the end of the transaction, but you cannot do it with INDEX (as far as I know). The workaround I can give is to use EXCLUDE as described below:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (                                                         
    ranking    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name         TEXT  NOT NULL,
    is_deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE USING BTREE (ranking WITH =) WHERE (not is_deleted) DEFERRABLE
);
```

Attention to the 'DEFERRABLE'

Here to populate initial data:

```
insert into my_table ( ranking,  name, is_deleted)
values 
  (1, 'A', true),
  (2, 'B', true),
  (1, 'C', true),
  (1, 'D', false),
  (2, 'E', false),
  (3, 'F', false);
```

Now if you execute :

```
UPDATE "my_table" AS t 
  SET "ranking" = v."ranking" 
FROM 
(VALUES(1, 'F', 'false'),(2, 'D', 'false'), (3, 'E', 'false'))
  AS v("ranking","name", "is_deleted")
WHERE v.name = t.name;
```

It should work.

And to test the uniqueness I tested it with :

```
insert into my_table ( ranking,  name, is_deleted)
  values 
  (3, 'G', false);
```